# Elasticsearch string matching multiple fields in query

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-date

I'm trying to query my Elastic Search database and match several fields, however, I get:

> [match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

Which is strange because surely I must be able to use `match` and then my field name to match some text right?

The fields I'm trying to query are inside my `data` object, which is custom, and since adding a (dot) doesn't work in here, I'm wrapping that, my data:

```
{
    "_index": "my_table",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "IVnGuXcBt3ZsPNCw23Eg",
    "_version": 1,
    "_seq_no": 0,
    "_primary_term": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "period_from": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "period_to": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "created_at": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                    "fielddata": true
                },
                "updated_at": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                    "fielddata": true
                }
            }
        },
        "data": {
            "dataset": "events",
            "event_category": "test1",
            "event_action": "test2",
            "event_count": "199",
            "period_from": "2021-02-19 00:02:00",
            "period_to": "2021-02-19 10:02:29",
            "created_at": "2021-02-19 10:02:79",
            "updated_at": "2021-02-19 10:02:79"
        },
        "period_from": "2021-02-19 00:02:00",
        "period_to": "2021-02-19 10:02:29",
        "created_at": "2021-02-19 10:02:18",
        "updated_at": "2021-02-19 10:02:18"
    }
}
```

What am I missing here:

```js
events = await elastic.find('my_table', {
  query: {
    match: {
      'data.event_category': 'test1'
    },
    match: {
      'data.event_action': 'test2'
    },
    range: {
      period_from: {
        gte: moment(from).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
      },
      period_to: {
        lte: moment(to).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: All the match and range conditions need to be wrapped inside a bool/must and/or bool/filter query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've [correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66276485/8160318) set up the date fields' mappings, use this:

```
{
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: [
        {
          match: {
            "data.event_action": "test2"
          }
        },
        {
          range: {
            period_from: {
              gte:  moment(from).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
            }
          }
        },
        {
          range: {
            period_to: {
              lte: moment(to).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, although returns nothing? Which is odd, no errors, I do indeed have data in the database though

Comment: Check my other answers to your previous questions first :)